# Cronjob Quartz format in yml

Tags: java, cron, quarkus, quartz

I have the application.yml with that entry:

```
cron:
  scheduler:
     expr: 0 0/60 * * * ?
```

when I try to inject the property in my Quarkus scheduler I get the message:

```
IllegalArgumentExpression: Cron expression contains 1 parts but we expect one of [6, 7]
```

I get this message for each example I try and I am not able to solve the problem.

Even:

```
expr: "0 0/60 * * * ?"
```

did not work.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "{cron.scheduler.expr}") 
void cronJobWithExpressionInConfig() {
   counter.incrementAndGet();
   System.out.println("Cron expression configured in application.yml");
}
```

I am happy for any advice.

Comment: How do you assign this property to Quarkus scheduler?

Comment: @marcin.programuje see my edited question

Comment: Should be a ```@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.scheduler.expr}")```

Comment: @marcin.programuje The annotation does **not** need the `$`, like specified in the guide (see example below). 
@s_bei Which version of Quarkus are you using? Both 1.9.0.Final and 1.9.2.Final work fine, when you pass a valid cron expression. Please see example below. 
Looking forward to getting some feedbacks from you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/scheduler) the value in the annotation is correct, but if you look at the paragraph [updating-the-application-configuration-file](https://quarkus.io/guides/scheduler#updating-the-application-configuration-file) the guide is using the file `application.properties`.

Since you are using an YAML file, I suspect you did not include a dependency that is needed (tested both version `1.9.0.Final` and `1.9.2.Final`):

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

On the contrary of Spring, this dependency must be explicitly listed in the pom.xm file.

Moreover, I would change the YAML file in this way:

```yaml
cron:
  scheduler:
     expr: "0 0/60 * * * ?"
```

***Disclamer***: I did not manage to replicate your error. Details provided are not sufficient.

**Edited**

Please, note that the cron expression itself is fishy... '0/60' does not make sense. That is the part that specify the minute of the hour the cron job will happen, for instance '0/40' says that one wants the job to be executed at minute 0 and minute 40th of each hour, for example at 00:00, 00:40,...,  14:00, 14:40, ... 23:00 and 23:40.

So your expression says to execute the job at XX:00 and XX:60 which does not exists.

If you check in the official docs of [Cron Trigger Tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html) in the **Minutes** line it clearly states that the values accepted are in the range of [0-59]

**Example**

Please, observe the following *(working)* java class:

```java
package com.acme.scheduled;

import io.quarkus.scheduler.Scheduled;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ScheduledActions {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledActions.class);

    private static final int lengthFrame = 120;
    private static final int lengthText = lengthFrame - 4;
    private static final String FRAME = StringUtils.repeat('*', lengthFrame);

    private void printFancyText(final String text) {
        final String centeredText;

        if(text.length() > lengthText ) {
            centeredText = StringUtils.abbreviate(text,"...", lengthText);
        } else if ( text.length() == lengthText) {
            centeredText = text;
        } else {
            centeredText = StringUtils.center(text, lengthText);
        }

        LOGGER.info(FRAME);
        LOGGER.info("* {} *", centeredText);
        LOGGER.info(FRAME);
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "{cron.scheduler.expr}")
    public void cronExpressionTrigger(){
        this.printFancyText("Firing from statically defined cron expression. Triggering method 'cronExpressionTrigger'.");
    }

    @Scheduled(delay = 5, delayUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS, every = "PT15S")
    public void delayTrigger() {
        this.printFancyText("Firing from delay express in seconds. Triggering method 'delayTrigger'.");
    }

    @Scheduled(every = "30s")
    public void periodicTrigger(){
        this.printFancyText("Firing from statically defined period. Triggering method 'periodicTrigger'.");
    }

}
```

The value of the cron expression is taken from the application.yml file, defined as following:

```yaml
cron:
  scheduler:
    expr: "0 0/1 * * * ?"       #   This works like a charm, with or without the '@' - I prefer with.
#    expr: "0 0/60 * * * ?"   >>> This does NOT work. It fails with error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Period 60 not in range [0, 59]
```